External hard drive with Ubuntu is not recognized
I just installed Ubuntu on a NUC, and to my great pleasure it works. Next that the NUC is now silent (which it totally was not when it was running Windows 10), however if I use a Western Digital external USB drive Ubuntu fails to recognize it. Based on what I read it if file system related, however I expect it happened before. Next is a screen of the message.


What is the file system that the external drive was formatted with? Your error screen shows it all. It is not formatted in a file system Ubuntu  uses.

It is not possible to see who has up voted a question. So if you have already thank you. If the answer is working for you please also accept it. That is when it will come up in searches as answered not till. BTW Changed my display name a bit do to several people with same name.

The external USB attached drive needs to be formatted with a File System that Ubuntu uses.
If you plan on using the drive both on Windows and Ubuntu then NTFS is the file system you need to format the drive with.
If you will only be using it on a Ubuntu OS then you should use the EXT4 File System.
Either way your solution is the same. Back up all the files from the External Drive to some place else. Format the drive as stated and then copy the files back on again.

Thx, good suggestion. however, the fs is ntfs. I'll on a 4 tb wd hd. I guess I still have to reformat or might there something else? Btw  already voted :-)

Please accept the answer. Like I already said if for Ubuntu only best to format as EXT4

will do. thx again

Sorry to ask again but is there a reason you have not accepted the answer?
